# Bootcamp Win7 partition does not load

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, partitioning, boot-camp

I am running Mac OS X and Bootcamp with Windows 7. I needed to have read/write access to data on Windows partition. Therefore I have created one more partition using Disk Utility.

The resulting partitions were as follows: 1. OS X 2. Fat32 (cut from OSX) 3. Windows 7

After reboot the windows partition does not show. I have only option to boot to Mac or to use Recovery disk.

After this I have removed the 2nd partition and tried to resize the OS X partition to its original size. This was however not possible. After reboot the problem is still the same: no Windows 7 partition is loaded.

How can I get my beloved windows 7 back?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed the current supported Bootcamp drivers on your system?  The best way to solve a problem like this is to use the `Windows Recovery Console`.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I tried to run Windows installer from DVD but when tried to recover windows I obtained: "This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of Windows".

Comment: You will need to figure out that seperate problem before we can proceed.